# Obtaining context in service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I'm developing a service started from activity. The service starts a thread that after a long work should call a method from the activity. How can I deliver link at the activity to the thread?

Comment: You have to make an effort in researching about Android Services.

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply bind to the service in order to start it. When bounded, you get the binder in your activity and register a callback in your service. When your thread has finished you call the callback method which goes up to your activity.

In other word, use `bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)` and get the binder from the serviceConnection implementation

```
private static ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

        mBinder = (YourBinder) service;
        mBinder.registerCallback(yourCallbackImplementation);


    }
};
```

And you use yourCallbackImplementation to get messages from the service.